# Failed to import several CSV files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wanted to import several `.csv` files into SQL Server, so I used `bulk insert` to do that. However, when I run this script, `bulk insert` only inserted the first row of each `.csv` file to the table, instead of all the rows.

I have been debugging on this problem for a whole day. Please do help me on this problem. Thanks

```
DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @fn VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @judge int
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @dir='D:\try\'
SET @path=''

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DirectoryTree2') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #DirectoryTree2;

CREATE TABLE #DirectoryTree2
(
     id int IDENTITY(1,1),
     fname VARCHAR(100), 
     d int,
     f int
);

INSERT INTO #DirectoryTree2 
    EXEC xp_dirtree 'D:\try\',1,1

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT fname from #DirectoryTree2)
BEGIN
     SET @sql = ''
     SET ROWCOUNT 1 --get the filename of the first row

     SELECT @ID = id, @fn = fname 
     FROM #DirectoryTree2

     SET @path = @dir + @fn

     SET @fn = REPLACE(@fn,'.csv','')
     SET @fn = REPLACE(@fn,'-','')

     SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE [try].[dbo].'+@fn+'
     (
     ID VARCHAR(50),JLBH VARCHAR(50),HPHM VARCHAR(50),HPZL VARCHAR(50),JGSJ VARCHAR(50),CLSD VARCHAR(50),ZGXS VARCHAR(50),ZDXS VARCHAR(50),CWKC VARCHAR(50),HPYS VARCHAR(50),CLLX VARCHAR(50),JLLX VARCHAR(50),HDSJ VARCHAR(50),BZWZDM VARCHAR(50),SBBH VARCHAR(50),CDBH VARCHAR(50),FXBH VARCHAR(50),TPSL VARCHAR(50),ZFBJ VARCHAR(50),SJLY VARCHAR(50),CCLX VARCHAR(50),BZ VARCHAR(200),CSYS VARCHAR(50),JLLB VARCHAR(50),XSFX VARCHAR(50),CSBJ VARCHAR(50),TPLX VARCHAR(50),XRSJ VARCHAR(50),DEALTIME1 VARCHAR(50),DEALTIME2 VARCHAR(50),DEALTIME3 VARCHAR(50),DEALTIME4 VARCHAR(50),TXFS VARCHAR(50),WFDM VARCHAR(50)
     )'

     EXEC(@sql)

     SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT try.dbo.'+@fn+' FROM ''' + @path + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 
            ) '
     EXEC(@sql)

     SET ROWCOUNT 0

     DELETE FROM #DirectoryTree2 
     WHERE id = @ID
END
```

Comment: Well, you have a `SET ROWCOUNT 1` at the beginning of our `WHILE` loop - that tells SQL Server to always limit its operations to **just one row** - and that's exactly what it's doing .....

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally ignore this problem.  It works well now.